# Magit: cannot commit error, unsure why

Tags: magit, doom

I am getting the error below and I have *no* clue what could be causing this. Any help is greatly appreciated:

```
  1 git --no-pager --literal-pathspecs -c core.preloadindex\=true -c log.showSignature\=false -c color.ui\=false -c color.diff\=false commit --
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
Waiting for Emacs...
*ERROR*: Wrong number of arguments: (1 . 4), 5
error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-plus\@28/28.0.50/bin/emacsclient --socket-name=/var/folders/77/7ht3td2j1vb00csyp1l4wlv40000gn/T/emacs501/server'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option
```

When I run `toggle-debug-on-error` I get the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Text Mode doesn’t support Hideshow Minor Mode")
  signal(error ("Text Mode doesn’t support Hideshow Minor Mode"))
  error("%s Mode doesn't support Hideshow Minor Mode" "Text")
  hs-grok-mode-type()
  hs-minor-mode()
  run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook text-mode-hook)
  apply(run-hooks (change-major-mode-after-body-hook text-mode-hook))
  run-mode-hooks(text-mode-hook)
  text-mode()
  set-auto-mode-0(text-mode nil)
  #f(compiled-function (&optional keep-mode-if-same) "Select major mode appropriate for current buffer.\n\nTo find the right major mode, this function checks for a -*- mode tag\nchecks for a `mode:' entry in the Local Variables section of the file,\nchecks if it uses an interpreter listed in `interpreter-mode-alist',\nmatches the buffer beginning against `magic-mode-alist',\ncompares the filename against the entries in `auto-mode-alist',\nthen matches the buffer beginning against `magic-fallback-mode-alist'.\n\nIf `enable-local-variables' is nil, or if the file name matches\n`inhibit-local-variables-regexps', this function does not check\nfor any mode: tag anywhere in the file.  If `local-enable-local-variables'\nis nil, then the only mode: tag that can be relevant is a -*- one.\n\nIf the optional argument KEEP-MODE-IF-SAME is non-nil, then we\nset the major mode only if that would change it.  In other words\nwe don't actually set it to the same mode the buffer already has." #<bytecode -0x5bd96aaf9730dd8>)()
  apply(#f(compiled-function (&optional keep-mode-if-same) "Select major mode appropriate for current buffer.\n\nTo find the right major mode, this function checks for a -*- mode tag\nchecks for a `mode:' entry in the Local Variables section of the file,\nchecks if it uses an interpreter listed in `interpreter-mode-alist',\nmatches the buffer beginning against `magic-mode-alist',\ncompares the filename against the entries in `auto-mode-alist',\nthen matches the buffer beginning against `magic-fallback-mode-alist'.\n\nIf `enable-local-variables' is nil, or if the file name matches\n`inhibit-local-variables-regexps', this function does not check\nfor any mode: tag anywhere in the file.  If `local-enable-local-variables'\nis nil, then the only mode: tag that can be relevant is a -*- one.\n\nIf the optional argument KEEP-MODE-IF-SAME is non-nil, then we\nset the major mode only if that would change it.  In other words\nwe don't actually set it to the same mode the buffer already has." #<bytecode -0x5bd96aaf9730dd8>) nil)
  so-long--set-auto-mode(#f(compiled-function (&optional keep-mode-if-same) "Select major mode appropriate for current buffer.\n\nTo find the right major mode, this function checks for a -*- mode tag\nchecks for a `mode:' entry in the Local Variables section of the file,\nchecks if it uses an interpreter listed in `interpreter-mode-alist',\nmatches the buffer beginning against `magic-mode-alist',\ncompares the filename against the entries in `auto-mode-alist',\nthen matches the buffer beginning against `magic-fallback-mode-alist'.\n\nIf `enable-local-variables' is nil, or if the file name matches\n`inhibit-local-variables-regexps', this function does not check\nfor any mode: tag anywhere in the file.  If `local-enable-local-variables'\nis nil, then the only mode: tag that can be relevant is a -*- one.\n\nIf the optional argument KEEP-MODE-IF-SAME is non-nil, then we\nset the major mode only if that would change it.  In other words\nwe don't actually set it to the same mode the buffer already has." #<bytecode -0x5bd96aaf9730dd8>))
  apply(so-long--set-auto-mode #f(compiled-function (&optional keep-mode-if-same) "Select major mode appropriate for current buffer.\n\nTo find the right major mode, this function checks for a -*- mode tag\nchecks for a `mode:' entry in the Local Variables section of the file,\nchecks if it uses an interpreter listed in `interpreter-mode-alist',\nmatches the buffer beginning against `magic-mode-alist',\ncompares the filename against the entries in `auto-mode-alist',\nthen matches the buffer beginning against `magic-fallback-mode-alist'.\n\nIf `enable-local-variables' is nil, or if the file name matches\n`inhibit-local-variables-regexps', this function does not check\nfor any mode: tag anywhere in the file.  If `local-enable-local-variables'\nis nil, then the only mode: tag that can be relevant is a -*- one.\n\nIf the optional argument KEEP-MODE-IF-SAME is non-nil, then we\nset the major mode only if that would change it.  In other words\nwe don't actually set it to the same mode the buffer already has." #<bytecode -0x5bd96aaf9730dd8>) nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :around #f(compiled-function (&optional keep-mode-if-same) "Select major mode appropriate for current buffer.\n\nTo find the right major mode, this function checks for a -*- mode tag\nchecks for a `mode:' entry in the Local Variables section of the file,\nchecks if it uses an interpreter listed in `interpreter-mode-alist',\nmatches the buffer beginning against `magic-mode-alist',\ncompares the filename against the entries in `auto-mode-alist',\nthen matches the buffer beginning against `magic-fallback-mode-alist'.\n\nIf `enable-local-variables' is nil, or if the file name matches\n`inhibit-local-variables-regexps', this function does not check\nfor any mode: tag anywhere in the file.  If `local-enable-local-variables'\nis nil, then the only mode: tag that can be relevant is a -*- one.\n\nIf the optional argument KEEP-MODE-IF-SAME is non-nil, then we\nset the major mode only if that would change it.  In other words\nwe don't actually set it to the same mode the buffer already has." #<bytecode -0x5bd96aaf9730dd8>) so-long--set-auto-mode)()
  apply(#f(advice-wrapper :around #f(compiled-function (&optional keep-mode-if-same) "Select major mode appropriate for current buffer.\n\nTo find the right major mode, this function checks for a -*- mode tag\nchecks for a `mode:' entry in the Local Variables section of the file,\nchecks if it uses an interpreter listed in `interpreter-mode-alist',\nmatches the buffer beginning against `magic-mode-alist',\ncompares the filename against the entries in `auto-mode-alist',\nthen matches the buffer beginning against `magic-fallback-mode-alist'.\n\nIf `enable-local-variables' is nil, or if the file name matches\n`inhibit-local-variables-regexps', this function does not check\nfor any mode: tag anywhere in the file.  If `local-enable-local-variables'\nis nil, then the only mode: tag that can be relevant is a -*- one.\n\nIf the optional argument KEEP-MODE-IF-SAME is non-nil, then we\nset the major mode only if that would change it.  In other words\nwe don't actually set it to the same mode the buffer already has." #<bytecode -0x5bd96aaf9730dd8>) so-long--set-auto-mode) nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  git-commit-setup()
  git-commit-setup-check-buffer()
  run-hooks(find-file-hook)
  #f(compiled-function (&optional error warn noauto after-find-file-from-revert-buffer nomodes) "Called after finding a file and by the default revert function.\nSets buffer mode, parses file-local and directory-local variables.\nOptional args ERROR, WARN, and NOAUTO: ERROR non-nil means there was an\nerror in reading the file.  WARN non-nil means warn if there\nexists an auto-save file more recent than the visited file.\nNOAUTO means don't mess with auto-save mode.\nFourth arg AFTER-FIND-FILE-FROM-REVERT-BUFFER is ignored\n(see `revert-buffer-in-progress-p' for similar functionality).\nFifth arg NOMODES non-nil means don't alter the file's modes.\nFinishes by calling the functions in `find-file-hook'\nunless NOMODES is non-nil." #<bytecode -0x9f4460c0a610514>)(nil t)
  apply(#f(compiled-function (&optional error warn noauto after-find-file-from-revert-buffer nomodes) "Called after finding a file and by the default revert function.\nSets buffer mode, parses file-local and directory-local variables.\nOptional args ERROR, WARN, and NOAUTO: ERROR non-nil means there was an\nerror in reading the file.  WARN non-nil means warn if there\nexists an auto-save file more recent than the visited file.\nNOAUTO means don't mess with auto-save mode.\nFourth arg AFTER-FIND-FILE-FROM-REVERT-BUFFER is ignored\n(see `revert-buffer-in-progress-p' for similar functionality).\nFifth arg NOMODES non-nil means don't alter the file's modes.\nFinishes by calling the functions in `find-file-hook'\nunless NOMODES is non-nil." #<bytecode -0x9f4460c0a610514>) (nil t))
  (if (setq doom-large-file-p (and buffer-file-name (not doom-large-file-p) (file-exists-p buffer-file-name) (condition-case nil (progn (> (nth 7 (file-attributes buffer-file-name)) (* 1024 1024 (assoc-default buffer-file-name doom-large-file-size-alist ...)))) (error nil)))) (prog1 (apply orig-fn args) (if (memq major-mode doom-large-file-excluded-modes) (setq doom-large-file-p nil) (if (fboundp 'so-long-minor-mode) (progn (so-long-minor-mode 1))) (message "Large file detected! Cutting a few corners to impr..."))) (apply orig-fn args))
  doom--optimize-for-large-files-a(#f(compiled-function (&optional error warn noauto after-find-file-from-revert-buffer nomodes) "Called after finding a file and by the default revert function.\nSets buffer mode, parses file-local and directory-local variables.\nOptional args ERROR, WARN, and NOAUTO: ERROR non-nil means there was an\nerror in reading the file.  WARN non-nil means warn if there\nexists an auto-save file more recent than the visited file.\nNOAUTO means don't mess with auto-save mode.\nFourth arg AFTER-FIND-FILE-FROM-REVERT-BUFFER is ignored\n(see `revert-buffer-in-progress-p' for similar functionality).\nFifth arg NOMODES non-nil means don't alter the file's modes.\nFinishes by calling the functions in `find-file-hook'\nunless NOMODES is non-nil." #<bytecode -0x9f4460c0a610514>) nil t)
  apply(doom--optimize-for-large-files-a #f(compiled-function (&optional error warn noauto after-find-file-from-revert-buffer nomodes) "Called after finding a file and by the default revert function.\nSets buffer mode, parses file-local and directory-local variables.\nOptional args ERROR, WARN, and NOAUTO: ERROR non-nil means there was an\nerror in reading the file.  WARN non-nil means warn if there\nexists an auto-save file more recent than the visited file.\nNOAUTO means don't mess with auto-save mode.\nFourth arg AFTER-FIND-FILE-FROM-REVERT-BUFFER is ignored\n(see `revert-buffer-in-progress-p' for similar functionality).\nFifth arg NOMODES non-nil means don't alter the file's modes.\nFinishes by calling the functions in `find-file-hook'\nunless NOMODES is non-nil." #<bytecode -0x9f4460c0a610514>) (nil t))
  #f(advice-wrapper :around #f(compiled-function (&optional error warn noauto after-find-file-from-revert-buffer nomodes) "Called after finding a file and by the default revert function.\nSets buffer mode, parses file-local and directory-local variables.\nOptional args ERROR, WARN, and NOAUTO: ERROR non-nil means there was an\nerror in reading the file.  WARN non-nil means warn if there\nexists an auto-save file more recent than the visited file.\nNOAUTO means don't mess with auto-save mode.\nFourth arg AFTER-FIND-FILE-FROM-REVERT-BUFFER is ignored\n(see `revert-buffer-in-progress-p' for similar functionality).\nFifth arg NOMODES non-nil means don't alter the file's modes.\nFinishes by calling the functions in `find-file-hook'\nunless NOMODES is non-nil." #<bytecode -0x9f4460c0a610514>) doom--optimize-for-large-files-a)(nil t)
  apply(#f(advice-wrapper :around #f(compiled-function (&optional error warn noauto after-find-file-from-revert-buffer nomodes) "Called after finding a file and by the default revert function.\nSets buffer mode, parses file-local and directory-local variables.\nOptional args ERROR, WARN, and NOAUTO: ERROR non-nil means there was an\nerror in reading the file.  WARN non-nil means warn if there\nexists an auto-save file more recent than the visited file.\nNOAUTO means don't mess with auto-save mode.\nFourth arg AFTER-FIND-FILE-FROM-REVERT-BUFFER is ignored\n(see `revert-buffer-in-progress-p' for similar functionality).\nFifth arg NOMODES non-nil means don't alter the file's modes.\nFinishes by calling the functions in `find-file-hook'\nunless NOMODES is non-nil." #<bytecode -0x9f4460c0a610514>) doom--optimize-for-large-files-a) (nil t))
  #f(advice-wrapper :before #f(advice-wrapper :around #f(compiled-function (&optional error warn noauto after-find-file-from-revert-buffer nomodes) "Called after finding a file and by the default revert function.\nSets buffer mode, parses file-local and directory-local variables.\nOptional args ERROR, WARN, and NOAUTO: ERROR non-nil means there was an\nerror in reading the file.  WARN non-nil means warn if there\nexists an auto-save file more recent than the visited file.\nNOAUTO means don't mess with auto-save mode.\nFourth arg AFTER-FIND-FILE-FROM-REVERT-BUFFER is ignored\n(see `revert-buffer-in-progress-p' for similar functionality).\nFifth arg NOMODES non-nil means don't alter the file's modes.\nFinishes by calling the functions in `find-file-hook'\nunless NOMODES is non-nil." #<bytecode -0x9f4460c0a610514>) doom--optimize-for-large-files-a) doom-first-file-hook-h)(nil t)
  apply(#f(advice-wrapper :before #f(advice-wrapper :around #f(compiled-function (&optional error warn noauto after-find-file-from-revert-buffer nomodes) "Called after finding a file and by the default revert function.\nSets buffer mode, parses file-local and directory-local variables.\nOptional args ERROR, WARN, and NOAUTO: ERROR non-nil means there was an\nerror in reading the file.  WARN non-nil means warn if there\nexists an auto-save file more recent than the visited file.\nNOAUTO means don't mess with auto-save mode.\nFourth arg AFTER-FIND-FILE-FROM-REVERT-BUFFER is ignored\n(see `revert-buffer-in-progress-p' for similar functionality).\nFifth arg NOMODES non-nil means don't alter the file's modes.\nFinishes by calling the functions in `find-file-hook'\nunless NOMODES is non-nil." #<bytecode -0x9f4460c0a610514>) doom--optimize-for-large-files-a) doom-first-file-hook-h) (nil t))
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer COMMIT_EDITMSG> "~/git/GPH-repo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG" nil nil "~/git/GPH-repo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG" (1273703 16777220))
  find-file-noselect("/Users/atanas/git/GPH-repo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG")
  #f(compiled-function (files proc &optional nowait) "Find FILES and return a list of buffers created.\nFILES is an alist whose elements are (FILENAME . FILEPOS)\nwhere FILEPOS can be nil or a pair (LINENUMBER . COLUMNNUMBER).\nPROC is the client that requested this operation.\nNOWAIT non-nil means this client is not waiting for the results,\nso don't mark these buffers specially, just visit them normally." #<bytecode 0x194e967cfea8742d>)((("/Users/atanas/git/GPH-repo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG")) #<process server <1>> nil)
  apply(#f(compiled-function (files proc &optional nowait) "Find FILES and return a list of buffers created.\nFILES is an alist whose elements are (FILENAME . FILEPOS)\nwhere FILEPOS can be nil or a pair (LINENUMBER . COLUMNNUMBER).\nPROC is the client that requested this operation.\nNOWAIT non-nil means this client is not waiting for the results,\nso don't mark these buffers specially, just visit them normally." #<bytecode 0x194e967cfea8742d>) ((("/Users/atanas/git/GPH-repo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG")) #<process server <1>> nil))
  #f(advice-wrapper :after #f(compiled-function (files proc &optional nowait) "Find FILES and return a list of buffers created.\nFILES is an alist whose elements are (FILENAME . FILEPOS)\nwhere FILEPOS can be nil or a pair (LINENUMBER . COLUMNNUMBER).\nPROC is the client that requested this operation.\nNOWAIT non-nil means this client is not waiting for the results,\nso don't mark these buffers specially, just visit them normally." #<bytecode 0x194e967cfea8742d>) server-visit-files--with-editor-file-name-history-exclude)((("/Users/atanas/git/GPH-repo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG")) #<process server <1>> nil)
  apply(#f(advice-wrapper :after #f(compiled-function (files proc &optional nowait) "Find FILES and return a list of buffers created.\nFILES is an alist whose elements are (FILENAME . FILEPOS)\nwhere FILEPOS can be nil or a pair (LINENUMBER . COLUMNNUMBER).\nPROC is the client that requested this operation.\nNOWAIT non-nil means this client is not waiting for the results,\nso don't mark these buffers specially, just visit them normally." #<bytecode 0x194e967cfea8742d>) server-visit-files--with-editor-file-name-history-exclude) ((("/Users/atanas/git/GPH-repo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG")) #<process server <1>> nil))
  server-visit-files((("/Users/atanas/git/GPH-repo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG")) #<process server <1>> nil)
  server-execute(#<process server <1>> (("/Users/atanas/git/GPH-repo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG")) nil nil nil nil nil)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x415a275082ff4d7>)()
  server-execute-continuation(#<process server <1>>)
  server-process-filter(#<process server <1>> "-dir /Users/atanas/git/GPH-repo/ -current-frame -t...")
```

Any idea what could be causing this error? See below for the relevant systemt info:

```bash
Mac OS X 10.15.7
Emacs 28.0.50 (emacs-plus distro via homebrew)
Doom v2.0.9 (HEAD -> develop f7293fb67 2020-11-11 20:33:27 -0500)
Magit not sure what exact version but it should be the latest
```

## Update

I had `(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook #'hs-minor-mode)` which I have since removed and get the error below with no backtrace error...

```
0 git --no-pager --literal-pathspecs -c core.preloadindex\=true -c log.showSignature\=false -c color.ui\=false -c color.diff\=false reset HEAD -- \+custom.el
Unstaged changes after reset:
M   +custom.el

  0 git --no-pager --literal-pathspecs -c core.preloadindex\=true -c log.showSignature\=false -c color.ui\=false -c color.diff\=false add -u -- \+custom.el
  1 git --no-pager --literal-pathspecs -c core.preloadindex\=true -c log.showSignature\=false -c color.ui\=false -c color.diff\=false commit --
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
Waiting for Emacs...
*ERROR*: Wrong number of arguments: (1 . 4), 5
error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-plus\@28/28.0.50/bin/emacsclient --socket-name=/var/folders/77/7ht3td2j1vb00csyp1l4wlv40000gn/T/emacs501/server'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

  0 git --no-pager --literal-pathspecs -c core.preloadindex\=true -c log.showSignature\=false -c color.ui\=false -c color.diff\=false push -v origin master\:refs/heads/master
Pushing to https://github.com/atanasj/.doom.d.git
To https://github.com/atanasj/.doom.d.git
 = [up to date]      master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'
Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 1):

This error was related to `magit` with `emacs 28.0.50` (see issues on `magit` repo for further info). I installed `emacs 27.1` via `homebrew emacs-plus@27` formula and everything is working as expected.